# Список юзеров на сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Всем привет! Решил сделать генератор таблицы юзеров на сервере. Начал с обычного получения ников юзеров.

```
@client.command()

async def members(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for member in guild.member:
        print(member.nick)
```

Когда запускаю бота и ввожу комманду на сервере в консоли выводится ник только бота, затем после него следует None. Так вот, мне необходима помощь - как сделать, чтобы выводился полный список юзеров на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно месяц назад шлюз дискорда был обновлен и теперь для того чтобы работать с объектами пользователей нужно выдавать намерения (`intents`). У вас проблема как раз таки в том, что **вы не выдали боту необходимые намерения**. Чтобы их выдать, вам нужно при инициализации бота, помимо префикса указать также намерения.

**Выдаем боту намерения при объявлении:**

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

---

**Если проблема осталась**, то попробуйте включить два пункта на странице вашего бота. Для этого зайдите в [раздел приложений](https://discord.com/developers/applications) и выберите вашего бота. Затем, слева, на вкладке "Bot"

[image: Бот]

Включите параметры `PRESENCE INTENT` и `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помогло, но частично. Когда ввожу команду, список на 70-80% состоит из None, остальное - ники учатсников. Возможно, это из-за использования member.nick.
P.S. проверил, None показывало из-за использования member.nick