# Как забрать у пользователя роль, зная только его ID? Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

У меня есть ID пользователя, и я хочу забрать у него роль. Как это можно сделать? Как я понял, мне нужен объект member. Спасибо!

Все, что у меня есть:

```
<RawReactionActionEvent 

message_id=889129526414688307 

user_id=760854742305079349 

channel_id=880382991476613160 

guild_id=761950725508956160 

emoji=  < PartialEmoji animated=False name='1️⃣' id=None>

event_type='REACTION_REMOVE' member=None>
```

Comment: а для вас весь интернет в помощь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906438/how-do-you-remove-a-role-from-a-user

Comment: увы, но я не могу так написать. Я использую событие on_raw_reaction_remove. И оно дает только ID

Comment: варианта два - хорошенько прошерстить документацию, которая я уверен хороша\найти что либо похожее на вашу проблему. либо же переписать методы

Comment: а как их переписать? Если бы я знал, то не писал бы сюда

Comment: ну вы говорите, что обрабатываете какое-то событие. попробуйте другой обработчик например, в дискорд апи я не шарю, но уверен что эта задача решаема

Comment: это единственный обработчик( а с тем, что задача решаема поспорить сложно. Нет нерешаемых задач

Comment: Документация: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_remove

Comment: ну так почитав, я уверен, что можно получить инстанс юзера по айди, а там надо думать

Comment: да вот не получается

Comment: мне по ID надо получить member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем команду и принимаем `id` пользователя в виде аргумента.

В переменную `ROLE_ID` укажите `id` роли, которую хотите выдать/забрать.

Код большой, потому что в нем прописано большинство возможных исключений

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

ROLE_ID = 794985313692286998

@bot.command()
async def give_role(ctx, user_id: int=None):
    if ctx.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
        await ctx.send('Данную команду нельзя использовать в личных сообщениях!')
        return
    if user_id == None:
        await ctx.send('Укажите `id` пользователя!')
        return
    else:
        member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=user_id)
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=ROLE_ID)
        await member.add_roles(role)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, укажите `id` пользователя. Не удалось преобразовать указанный аргумент в число!')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Я провел некоторые исследования и выяснил, что бот по какой-то причине не видит всех пользователей. Он видит количество пользователей сервера и себя. Даже других ботов он не видит. Т. е. в ```ctx.guild.members``` хранится только сам бот и все. Поэтому ваш код не работает(((

Comment: @Daniel, обратите внимание на 3 строчку моего кода. У вас такой фрагмент есть в вашем коде? `intents=discord.Intents.all()`

Comment: Выдает ошибку ```discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000000002D741F0>```

Comment: Вам с тексте ошибки написали, что нужно зайти на страницу бота и включить `намерения` в настройках :). В общем, я уже отвечал когда-то на такой вопрос, здесь подробно написано как это исправить: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213684/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5/1213716#1213716)

Comment: спасибо большое!