# пишу бота для Discord на Python, использую member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members), но member = None. Почему?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

код программы:

```
import discord
import config



client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is logged in.")

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    messge_id = payload.message_id
    if messge_id == config.POST_ID:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == "":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Dota2")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="CS")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="GTA")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Fortnite")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "️":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Rocket League")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="герой")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("member not found")
                print(payload.user_id)
                print(guild.members)
                print(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
                print(guild)
        else:
            print("Role not found")

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    pass
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с участниками серверов боту необходимо выдать намерения. Их отсутствие - довольно распространенная проблема, поэтому подробнее можете почитать в одном из моих [**старых ответов**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213684/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/1213716#1213716).

Если вкратце, то нужно включить параметры `PRESENCE INTENT` и `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` на [**странице вашего бота**](https://discord.com/developers/applications), на вкладке **Bot**.

А затем выдать намерения боту при инициализации:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

---

А, собственно, для получения объекта участника сервера (`member`) я бы рекомендовал использовать функцию `get()` из модуля `discord.utils`:

Она первым аргументом принимает список/кортеж или любой другой перечисляемый объект, а вторым аргументом - свойство конкретного объекта, который нужно найти. Подробнее можно почитать [**здесь**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils#discord.utils.get)

**Пример:**

```
# получаем объект сервера
guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)

# получаем участника используя id
member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
```

При этом, если такого участника нет, `member` примет значение `None`