# Не работает команда пинга в личные сообщения

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-api

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx):
    user=await bot.get_user_info("698222023381483572")
    await bot.send_message(user, "Your message goes here")
```

выдает в консоли:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\pybot\bot.py", line 140, in dm
    user=await bot.get_user_info("698222023381483572")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем начать писать код с новой для вас библиотекой, нужно сначала ознакомиться [документацией](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) или какими-либо онлайн-туториалами, в которых показывается как с этой библиотекой работать.

Возникает вполне логичный вопрос: с чего вы взяли, что в библиотеке `discord-py` объект `commands.Bot` имеет функцию `get_user_info()`, а также `send_message()`?

---

Если почитать документацию по вашему объекту [`bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot), то можно увидеть, что в списке методов у него есть асинхронный метод [`fetch_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_user), который принимает в качестве аргумента `id` не в виде строки, как у вас, а в виде целого числа `int`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в случае успеха возвращает вам объект пользователя, свойства и методы которого вы тоже можете найти в документации: [discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User)

---

И теперь, посмотрев список методов пользователя, можно обнаружить, что для отправки сообщения этому пользователю, вызывать функцию `send()` (а не `send_message()`) нужно именно у пользователя или канала, в который вы хотите отправить сообщения, а не у объекта `bot`.

---

Научитесь пользоваться документацией и от подобных проблем можно будет избавляться за пару минут, просто почитав об этом, вместо того, чтобы ждать, пока вам через пару часов ответят другие люди :)

Краткое руководство есть у меня на `GitHub`: [ссылка](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-discord-py)

**Код должен выглядеть так:**

```
# для использования await bot.fetch_user(), боту нужно выдать намерения
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(698222023381483572)
    await user.send("Your message goes here")
```

По поводу `intents`, для использования `await bot.fetch_user()` можете узнать [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213684/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/1213716#1213716)